# AngularJS function in dialog called several times

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Please see this code.

html code

```
<script type="application" id = "abc">
  <md-dialog>
    {{loadServerFile();}}
  </md-dialog>
</script>
```

javascript code

```
    loadServerFile : function(){
      $.ajax({
       url: "/homepage/create"
       success: function(){
          console.log("success");
          $scope.closeDialog();
        }
      });
    }
```

Here `closeDialog` close the `id = 'abc'` dialog.

But `console.log("success")` calling is doing more than 10 times.

Why this kind of problem happen?
How can I make this function call once?

javascript code

```
angular.module("imageedit").service('canvas',['$rootScope','$mdDialog'],function($rootScope, $mdDialog){
...
start: function(url){
$mdDialog.show({
   template: $('abc').html()
   controller: 'GGG'
   clickOutsidetoClose: false,
   })
   ...
 }
   ...
})
```

Here I called `$mdDialog.show` to call dialog.
But in fact I only want to call `loadServerfile` in `GGG` controller.
Have you got any answer?
What I expect: `$rootScope.call(loadServerFile);`

Comment: Don't make an ajax call from the view, otherwise it will be called on every digest cycle which is what's happening with you. Call `loadServerFile` from a controller

Comment: I am not sure how can I call the loadServerFile from a controller.

Comment: I also want to do that, but It's not my own code I mean start from scratch.
I don't know the internal action.

Comment: Still not sure what you want to do with the data. Two new questions: what html does $('abc').html() point to? And what do you want with the result from /homepage/create? Does it need to be displayed in the dialog? And what does the GGG controller look like?

Comment: GGG controller contains javascript function loadServerFile.

Comment: I don't want to make dialog to be shown but what I do to call loadServerfile is showing the abc dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the new information, that you **do not want the dialog**, in your GGG controller, add this code, which will run one time. It will place the result of the call in `$scope.homepageCreateResult`. If you don't need to make this call at all, and do not need the dialog, delete all of the code you reference.

```
   $scope.homepageCreateResult = {};
   $http.get("/homepage/create")
        .then(function(resp) {
            console.log('success', resp);
            $scope.homepageCreateResult = resp.data;
        });
```

In your HTML, just remove all of this:

```
<script type="application" id = "abc">
  <md-dialog>
    {{loadServerFile();}}
  </md-dialog>
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In many of code, `closeDialog` function only hides dialog and not really close dialog.
And `showDialog` can be called lots of times.
You cannot see that but according to your question, `console.log` is called lots of times so my expection will be right.